# Get all properties marked with [JsonIgnore] attribute

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a class MyClass with a list of properties.

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Attribute1]
    [Attribute2]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int? Prop1 { get; set; }

    [Attribute1]
    [Attribute8]
    public int? Prop2 { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [Attribute2]
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

I would like retrieve properties that are no marked with [JsonIgnore] attribute.

JsonIgnore is an attribute by http://www.newtonsoft.com/json

So, in this example, I would like to have the property "Prop2".

I tried with

```
var props = t.GetProperties().Where(
                prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(JsonIgnore)));
```

or

```
var props = t.GetProperties().Where(
                    prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute)));
```

where *t* is the type of MyClass but the method return 0 elements.

can you help me, please?
Thanks

Comment: I know, but as you can see I tried that solution with no results.

Comment: Have you tried the non-static approach as suggested in the duplicate?

Comment: You want the ones that *don't* have the attribute. So you need to *negate* the check.

Comment: @Luaan I know but is not this the problem. The problem is how to identify correctly the attribute [JsonIgnore]

Comment: You already have the `JsonIgnoreAttribute` type - that's what you used to mark the member in the first place. Just use the same one.

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes, with no results.

Comment: Your second attempt should work. Are the properties in your actual code `public`?

Comment: @fknx yes are public.

Comment: Your second code example works for me without a hitch. Are you sure your example is representative of your actual code?

Comment: @J.Steen yes, I'm sure

Comment: Well, I'm not, considering the example works. It seems like there's something else missing here.

Comment: @elvius I agree with J.Steen. The code should be working fine. See this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mUl11V) as reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
typeof(MyClass).GetProperties()
               .Where(property => 
                      property.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                              .OfType<JsonIgnoreAttribute>()
                              .Any()
                     );
```

Specifying the type in the `GetCustomAttibutes` call can be more performant, in addition, you might want the logic to be reusable so you could use this helper method:

```
static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesWithAttribute<TType, TAttribute>()
{
    Func<PropertyInfo, bool> matching = 
            property => property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false)
                                .Any();

    return typeof(TType).GetProperties().Where(matching);
}
```

Usage:

```
var properties = GetPropertyWithAttribute<MyClass, JsonIgnoreAttribute>();
```

**EDIT:**
I'm not sure, but you might be after the properties without the attribute, so you could just negate the find predicate:

```
static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesWithoutAttribute<TType, TAttribute>()
{
    Func<PropertyInfo, bool> matching =
            property => !property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false)
                                .Any();

    return typeof(TType).GetProperties().Where(matching);
}
```

Or you could use simple libraries such as **Fasterflect**:

```
typeof(MyClass).PropertiesWith<JsonIgnoreAttribute>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The attributes are on properties, not the class itself. So , you'll need to iterate over the properties, and then try to find those attributes -

```
foreach (var item in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties())
        {
            var attr = item.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonIgnoreAttribute), false);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This selects all the `Names` of the attributes with your `IgnoreColumnAttribute` `attribute` as an `Array`. Use `!Attribute.IsDefined` to select the opposite. This uses much less resources than the other answers due to the `Attribute.IsDefined` filtering vs the expensive `GetCustomAttributes`

```
dynamic props = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties().Where(prop =>
Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(IgnoreColumnAttribute))).Select(propWithIgnoreColumn => 
propWithIgnoreColumn.Name).ToArray;
```